# Regression error in 2 class classification

Tags: python

And I am trying to do logistic regression with g1 as class 0 and g2 as class 1:

```
ft=np.vstack((g1,g2)) #data stacked on each other
class = np.hstack((np.zeros(f), np.ones(f))) #class values in column matrix
clc=np.reshape(cl,(2*f,1)) #class values in an array
w=np.zeros((2,1))   #weights matrix

for n in range(0,5000):
    s = np.dot(ft, w)

    prediction = (1 / (1 + np.exp(-s))) #sigmoid function

    gr = (np.dot(ft.T, class - prediction)) #gradient of loss function
    w += 0.01 * gr
print (w)
```

I evaluate my result using sklearn:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import
```

And I get :

w=[[6.77812323]
 [2.91052504]]

coef_=[[1.22724506 1.10456893]

Do you know why the weights do not match? Is there anything wrong with my math?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just missing the step where you calculate the gradient average. Also note that instead of using `class`, I'm using `clc`:

```
N = len(ft)    
for _ in range(5000):
    s = np.dot(ft, w)
    prediction = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-s))  # sigmoid function

    gr = np.dot(ft.T, clc - prediction)  # gradient of loss function
    gr /= N  # calculate gradient average

    w += 0.01 * gr  # update weights
```

**Adding entire code**

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

np.random.seed(1)  # for reproducibility

f = 100
mean1 = [-5, -3]
cov1 = [[5, 0], [0, 3]]
mean2 = [4, 3]
cov2 = [[3, 0], [0, 2]]
g1 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean1, cov1, f)
g2 = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean2, cov2, f)

ft = np.vstack((g1, g2))  # data stacked on each other
cls = np.hstack((np.zeros(f), np.ones(f)))  # class values in column matrix
clc = np.reshape(cls,(2 * f, 1))  # class values in an array
w = np.zeros((2, 1))  # weights matrix

N = len(ft)
for _ in range(5000):
    s = np.dot(ft, w)
    prediction = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-s))  # sigmoid function

    gr = np.dot(ft.T, clc - prediction)  # gradient of loss function
    gr /= N  # calculate gradient average

    w += 0.01 * gr  # update weights

print("w = {}".format(w))

lr = LogisticRegression(fit_intercept=False)
lr.fit(ft, cls)
print("lr.coef_ = {}".format(lr.coef_))
```

**Output**

```
w = [[1.28459432]
 [1.07186532]]
lr.coef_ = [[1.23311932 1.0363586 ]]
```

Comment: I tried with the gradient 2*f or N but it still does not work I get even weirder results do you have other ideas? Thanks a lot for taking time to answer!!

Comment: @KonstantinosKarras-Kallidromi Did you reset your weights to 0 before each run? Also the weights won't exactly match the weights from the `LogisticRegression` but they should be close. For example, when I ran it, `w = array([[1.26769744], [1.04296564]])` and `lr.coef_ = array([[1.21024852, 1.0130732 ]])`

Comment: Isn't resetting the weight automatic using w=np.zeros((2,1)) in my code? I dont know why its not the right result im staring to lose it. I just executed it again with the divided by N part (copied the code in the answer) and got w=[[0.99741827][1.34016279]] and lr.coef_=[[2.07139834 5.5150658 ]]. I was thinking maybe I am getting another multiple of the same vector like instead of [1 1] i am getting [5 5]. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, reset with `w = np.zeros((2,1))`. Are you using `clc - prediction` instead of `class - prediction`? Also, in your code, you have `clc = np.reshape(cl,(2*f,1))`, which I modified to `clc = np.reshape(class,(2*f,1))` since you created `class` in the previous line.

Comment: Yeah I am using clc I don't know anymore honestly thanks alot man

Comment: @KonstantinosKK No problem. If you want, I can share the entire code for you to reproduce.

Comment: @KonstantinosKK Done :)

Comment: I figured out the problem I was using more than 5000 iterations. I thought this way the result would be more accurate. Thank you so much for all the help. One last thing is there a specific number of iterations that will provide a more ideal result?

Comment: No, there's no magic number for iterations. You usually set the iterations to some large number and then have the algorithm terminate early if the cost function gets really close to zero, or when successive iterations result in very little change in the cost function.